# Where can I find java sample for generating google API access token via client sdk?

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-oauth, access-token

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wli0liBhGRs&t=248s) mentioned using http get to retrieve google API access token given client id, client secret and refresh token. However, I don't seem to find the corresponding client sdk call documentation, nor sample code, for that. Can someone please point me to that if exists? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found this works:

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("client_id", clientId);
    json.put("client_secret", clientSecret);
    json.put("refresh_token", refreshToken);
    json.put("type", "authorized_user");

    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    var credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);

    accessToken = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).